# Relative path vs absolute paths

Tags: java, file

I have a java web application that reads files from the system, these files can be anywhere on the system.

I know if the file is in the webapp itself its always better to use relative path, but for files outside is it better to use absolute or relative? I just think using relative is a bit pointless, but many senior developers have suggested i use relative.

Would be interested in hearing thoughts, and what the practice is?

Comment: It doesn't really matter as long as the code works. If your senior developers think otherwise, ask them why.

Comment: Would this post fit better on StackExchange's Programmers ?

Comment: @Ephi when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: @gnat Yep, no need to post it again on the other site, but what about a migration ?

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you should always use relative paths **where possible**. This is the **best practice**.

But if you can be absolutely (get it?) sure that file will stay there and is outside your actual application, you can refer it with an absolute path and it should be fine.

There are **no real rules** for when to use which... Id use it **just for external stuff** like this

The advantage you get with relative paths, obviously, is that its a lot more dynamic then using absolute paths.

Answer (score 0):

It just depends on what you *know*. You have a webapp - that means that it's deployed on a server (like glassfish).

- Up to the level of your servers folder it will be better to use relative paths - because you *know* the file structure up to that point and can localise everything without extra knowledge about the rest of the filesystem.
- For files outside that you can't guarantee anything (it's perfectly legal to put and move server installation absolutely anywhere on the system) so absolute paths will be a more flexible choice.